# Restrict the multiple tabs to open in a same browser

Tags: typescript, angular7

In my application, it should not allow the user to open the application in multiple tabs for same browser. I need to implement this for some security purpose. How can I implement this in angular 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shorter version with localStorage and Storage listener

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Broadcast that you're opening a page.
        localStorage.openpages = Date.now();
        var onLocalStorageEvent = function(e){
            if(e.key == "openpages"){
                // Listen if anybody else is opening the same page!
                localStorage.page_available = Date.now();
            }
            if(e.key == "page_available"){
                alert("One more page already open");
            }
        };
        window.addEventListener('storage', onLocalStorageEvent, false);
</script>
```